# Mailman delivery troubles

Tags: hosting, mailing-list, mailman

I have apparently posted at the wrong place (superuser.com) for this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/99532/mailman-delivery-troubles), so I'll just repost it here. Hope those of you who read both sites are not going to be offended.

It's about mailing list management software called Mailman from GNU. Here are the details:

Hosting provider: Vlexofree
Domain: www.sysil.com with Google Apps
Mailing List created from hosting cpanel: team4@sysil.com

I have registered a list of subscribers, and tried sending an email to team4@sysil.com. I got the following error message:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    team4@sysil.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 23si6479194ewy.44 (state 14).

----- Original message -----

MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.216.90.136 with SMTP id e8mr1469147wef.110.1264220118960; Fri,
       22 Jan 2010 20:15:18 -0800 (PST)
Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2010 20:15:18 -0800
Message-ID: <14c4beb31001222015h4ca1d5fcw2ebcabc69893f926@mail.gmail.com>
Subject:
From: Stanley Lee <stanigator@gmail.com>
To: team4@sysil.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=0016e6dab0931bccc3047dcd2f1e
- Show quoted text -
```

Is there any way of fixing this problem? I would like to be able to have this mailing list to work through my hosting and domain. Thanks in advance.